# Java insert method in complete binary tree almost working

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I asked this before, but I still haven't been able to fix the insert() method inside my CompleteTree class. I'm trying to create a complete binary tree (not a binary search tree - it doesn't matter what the value inside the tree node is). So the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompleteTree tree = new CompleteTree();
    tree.insert(1);
    tree.insert(2);
    tree.insert(3);
    tree.insert(4);
    tree.insert(5);
    tree.insert(6);
    tree.inorder();
}
```

should create a tree that looks like this:

```
                1
              /   \
            2       3
           / \     /
         4    5   6
```

And it should print out 4 2 5 1 6 3

At first I thought my code worked, but I quickly realized there was a problem. My insertions will work up to 11. However, when I try inserting 12, it becomes a left child of 8 instead of 6.

```
                  1
              /      \
             2         3
           /   \      /  \ 
         4      5    6    7
        / \    / \     
       8   9  10 11  
// Code works fine up to this point
```

After reviewing my code, I can see why 12 gets inserted there, and I can see the problem with my code, but I have no idea how I would go about fixing it so that the nodes get inserted in the correct order. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

TreeNode.java

```
public class TreeNode {

    private Object value;
    private TreeNode left, right;

    public TreeNode(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

    public TreeNode(Object value, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public void setValue(Object theNewValue) {
        value = theNewValue;
    }

    public void setLeft(TreeNode theNewLeft) {
        left = theNewLeft;
    }

    public void setRight(TreeNode theNewRight) {
        right = theNewRight;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public TreeNode getLeft() {
        return this.left;
    }

    public TreeNode getRight() {
        return this.right;
    }

}
```

BinaryTree.java:

```
public abstract class BinaryTree {

    private TreeNode root;

    public BinaryTree() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    public void setRoot(TreeNode newNode) {
        this.root = newNode;
    }

    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return this.root;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (this.root == null);
    }

    public abstract void insert(Comparable item);
    public abstract TreeNode find(Comparable key);

} // end of class
```

CompleteTree.java:

```
public class CompleteTree extends BinaryTree {

    public CompleteTree() {
        super();
    }

    public void insert(Comparable item) {
        if(this.getRoot() == null) {
            this.setRoot(new TreeNode(item));
            return;
        }

        TreeNode t = this.getRoot();
        while(t != null) {
            if(t.getLeft() == null) {
                t.setLeft(new TreeNode(item));
                return;
            }
            else if(t.getRight() == null) {
                t.setRight(new TreeNode(item));
                return;
            }
            else {
                int lCount = countChildren(t.getLeft());
                int rCount = countChildren(t.getRight());
                if(lCount == rCount)
                    t = t.getLeft();
                else if(lCount == 0 || lCount == 1)
                    t = t.getLeft();
                else
                    t = t.getRight();
            }
        }
    }

    public int countChildren(TreeNode t) {
        int count = 0;
        if(t.getLeft() != null)
            count++;
        if(t.getRight() != null)
            count++;
        return count;
    }

    public TreeNode find(Comparable key) {
        TreeNode p = this.getRoot();
        while(p != null && key.compareTo(p.getValue()) != 0) {
            if(key.compareTo(p.getValue()) < 0)
                p = p.getLeft();
            else
                p = p.getRight();
        }
        return p;
    }

    public BinaryTree swapSubtrees() {
        doSwap(this.getRoot());
        return this;
    }

    private void doSwap(TreeNode p) {
        if(p != null) {
            TreeNode temp = p.getLeft();
            p.setLeft(p.getRight());
            p.setRight(temp);
            doSwap(p.getLeft());
            doSwap(p.getRight());
        }
    }

    public void inorder() {
        doInorderTraversal(this.getRoot());
    }

    private void doInorderTraversal(TreeNode t) {
        if(t != null) {
            doInorderTraversal(t.getLeft());
            System.out.print(t.getValue() + " ");
            doInorderTraversal(t.getRight());
        }
    }

}
```

CompleteTreeDemo.java:

```
public class CompleteTreeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompleteTree tree = new CompleteTree();
        tree.insert(1);
        tree.insert(2);
        tree.insert(3);
        tree.insert(4);
        tree.insert(5);
        tree.insert(6);
        tree.insert(7);
        tree.insert(8);
        tree.insert(9);
        tree.insert(10);
        tree.insert(11);
        tree.insert(12); // This gets inserted into the wrong place
        tree.inorder();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `countChildren()` method doesn't seem very comprehensive.

Comment: Edit: 

It just counts the children of a particular node. If that node has a left child, count is incremented. If that node has a right child, count is incremented again.

Comment: It doesn't count how many children that a node has though. at the 12th insert, countChildren of the root node will return 2. This is not usually what is intended when you want to build a binary tree. Consider that then since you count children of the left and right node of the root, you get 2 on each, and then your function chooses the left subtree.

Comment: Right, I see why it may go to the wrong node when both nodes have the same children. I don't know how I would go about changing my insert method to make sure I traverse correctly.

Comment: maybe this wikipedia article will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap
You are looking to implement the shape property of the heap, not necessarily the heap property. I am unfortunately unable to write up a full answer right now, maybe I will later though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm basically trying to create a heap except without any reheapification upward/downward, And that would be very much appreciated, thanks for the tips! Right now, I'm changing my countChildren() method to be recursive so that it correctly outputs the total number of children for a specific node and I'm going to see if I can do something with that.